# v-show on v-for creates unwanted return transition

Tags: performance, vue.js, transition

I am facing a performance issue with `v-for` on a big array.
The problem is that the `v-for` is re-generating all the filtered rows each time you change the filter. We solved this by doing a combination of `v-show` and `v-if` on the `v-for` element. This worked perfectly, saving us ~700ms in re-painting each time you filter the array.

The drawback of doing this is that it makes the [`transition-group`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions) go (bananas)

You can see this in action in the example below by filtering something, then clearing the filter. By using `v-show`, the elements do a weird transition from the top-left corner. This is not what I expect.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      filter: null,
      people: [],
      useVshow: true,
      settings: {
        opacityOnly: false
      }
    }
  },

  created() {
    /* Irerelevant for issue - Just some fancy example code: */
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
      arr.push({
        id: i,
        name: `person ${i}`,
        age: i,
        face: Math.floor(Math.random() * 9),
        show: true
      });
    }
    this.people = arr;
  },

  computed: {
    filteredPeople: function() {
      return this.filter ? this.people.filter(person => person.name.includes(this.filter)) : this.people
    }
  },

  watch: {
    filter() {
      for (const i of this.people) {
        i.show = this.filter ? i.name.includes(this.filter) : true;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
}

.opacity-only {
  transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}

.list-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}

.list-enter,
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.container {
  max-width: 520px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Irerelevant for issue - Just some fancy example code: */

input {
  width: 150px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.card .info p {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

.card .info .name {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #48484c;
}

.card .info .age {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #656565;
}

.card .avatar {
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<main id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <label for="filter">Filter by name:</label>
    <input name="filter" v-model="filter"> Use v-show: <input type="checkbox" v-model="useVshow">
    <br>Only trantition opacity: <input type="checkbox" v-model="settings.opacityOnly">

    <transition-group name="list" tag="div" class="wrapper">

      <template v-if="useVshow">
        <div v-for="person in people" v-show="person.show" :key="person.id" class="card" :class="{'opacity-only': settings.opacityOnly}">
          <img class="avatar" :src="`https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/${person.face}.jpg`">
          <div class="info">
            <p class="name">{{person.name}}</p>
            <p class="age">{{person.age}} years old</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>

      <template v-else>
        <div v-for="person in filteredPeople" :key="person.id" class="card">
          <img class="avatar" :src="`https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/${person.face}.jpg`">
          <div class="info">
            <p class="name">{{person.name}}</p>
            <p class="age">{{person.age}} years old</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>

    </transition-group>
  </div>
</main>
```

Why is this happening, and is there any way one can make the return-transition the same as if you do not have a `v-show`?

`EDIT:` Added option to only transition opacity as @Sitethief pointed out

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `transition: all` applies a transition to all CSS properties. This includes the `position: absolute;`  If you inspect in the developer while toggling the filter you can see this live. If you change the transition to something like   `transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;` the list items won't start in the left corner.

Comment: Good idea! I tried your solution adding only transition for opacity. However, this does fix the issue regarding elements flying in from the left, but it also removes the "slide" effect that is wanted